# Read Json file with non-ascii keys with python - how to reference the keys?

Tags: python, json, unicode, character-encoding

I have the following json:

```
{"Rotações": "string"}
```

And this python script with the corresponding result:

```
import json

with open('apaga.json') as jsonin:
    jsondict = json.load(jsonin)

print(jsondict)

> {'RotaÃ§Ãµes': 'string'}
```

So I don't know how to call this `RotaÃ§Ãµes` key, since it corresponds to `Rotações`.

The following does not work:

```
print(jsondict['Rotações'.encode('latin')])

> KeyError: b'Rota\xe7\xf5es'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding to `"utf-8"`

**Ex:**

```
print(jsondict['Rotações'.decode('utf-8')])
```

Tested in **python2.7**